# Erro ao colocar o composer como global MAC

Tags: php, composer

Pessoal instalei o composer em meu mac por este comando :

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ele baixou o composer.phar e testei :

```
php compser.phar
```

Me retornou tudo ok
Porém quando tentei usar o comando :

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Para deixá-lo como global me retorna :

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory
```

Como posso resolver ?
Obrigado

UPDATE
Li em um tópico que devemos mover o composer assim :

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

Porem da este erro :

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/bin/composer: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para qualquer pessoa que estiver tendo esse problema, é necessário reiniciar o seu `mac` e pressionar `cmd + r` durante a inicialização.

Em seguida, entrar em `utilities > terminal` e digitar os seguintes comandos:

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

Isso está acontecendo por conta da Proteção da Integridade do Sistema. Veja mais informações [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

Essa resposta foi traduzida do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled).

Comment: Não se esqueça de votar nas respostas originais :D